# How can I stop one of events?

Tags: javascript

```
input.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){   ......      });
input.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event){   .........    });
input.addEventListener("click", function(event){    ..........     });
```

I have set up 3 events in the input element. After clicking the mouse button to type text, I want to know how I can stop the first and second event and the third can be maintained even if the mouse cursor is positioned out of the input field.

I tried these functions:

```
event.preventDefault()
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is a classic example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: attempting to answer to the question, I think you could just have an handler set for each of those events that will check the value of a given flag in a higher scope that you will change from the click event handler ruling the game. Of course you can't change the dynamics of different events from their handlers like you are attempting there

Comment: `input.removeEventListener(...)`?

Comment: So if the input has focus, you do not want the mouseout event to fire? Hard to give a great answer since we do not know what you are trying to actually prevent.

Answer (score 2):

Base on Diego D answer in the comments, you can do something like this.

```
let mouseOutFlag = false;
let mouseOverFlag = false;

input.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){  
   if(mouseOverFlag) return;
   ... 
   mouseOverFlag = true;
});
input.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event){ 
   if(mouseOutFlag) return;  
   ...
   mouseOutFlag = true;
});

input.addEventListener("click", function(event){    ..........     });
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. However before clicking the mouse button, first and second event work only once. These events should be able to keep working before clicking (third event)

Comment: Thanks Kakiz. Your answer guide to problem solving.

Answer (score 1):

`mouseover`, `mouseout`, `click` are separate events. They are not linked to one mouse action.

You would need to rewrite the code to `removeEventListener` on any of the actions inside the added listeners. for example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input-element");

function thirdEvent(event) {
  console.log("third event")
  // Remove the first and second event listeners
  input.removeEventListener("mouseover", firstEvent);
  input.removeEventListener("mouseout", secondEvent);
}

function firstEvent(event) {
  console.log("mouseover")
}

function secondEvent(event) {
  console.log("mouseOut")
}
input.addEventListener("mouseover", firstEvent);

input.addEventListener("mouseout", secondEvent);



document.addEventListener("click", thirdEvent);
```

```css
div {
  background: #FED;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input-element">INPUT-ELEMENT</div>
```

---

some theory

`event.preventDefault()` is used to prevent the default action of an event from happening. For example, if you have a link ( tag) that you want to prevent from navigating to its default location when clicked, you can use event.preventDefault() to stop the link from navigating to its default location.

`event.stopImmediatePropagation()` is used to stop the propagation of an event to **other listeners**. When an event is triggered, it bubbles up from the target element to its parent elements. If you have multiple event listeners attached to the same element, they will be executed in the order in which they were added. If you want to stop the propagation of the event to other listeners, you can use event.stopImmediatePropagation().

Comment: i doubt they want to remove the event.

Comment: if so, then kakiz's answer should help out https://stackoverflow.com/a/75510816/2119863

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question.

There are two ways.
first one is using preventDefault().

```
input.addEventListener("click", function(event){ 
       event.preventDefault();     
                ..........     });
```

the other one is using third parameter of AddEventListener().

```
input.addEventListener("click", function(event){      
            ..........     },
           once = false);
```

If the once is true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked. If not specified, defaults to false.